# How to run packaged electron app on linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, electron

I haven't used Linux much but I'm trying to run an application which I've packaged using electron-packager.

So while on Linux, I can run `npm start` and my app works fine. But when I  package it, there doesn't seem to be an installer or anything. Packaging and running on Windows work fine.

I packaged using:

```
npm run package-linux
```

Edit as requested:

I'm using Linux mint-19.1-cinnamon-64bit.

The package script I used is;

```
"package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
```

Running the `npm run package-linux` completes successfully and produces a folder called `electron-tutorial-app-linux-x64` in a release-builds folder.

Comment: It would help if you mentioned which Linux distro & version you're using, what the `package-linux` script is and _exactly_ what it outputs.

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz sorry about that I've included more info.

Comment: It would also help if you mentioned what the `electron-tutorial-app-linux-x64` folder the script created contains :)

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz It's just the code from this video :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN1Czs0m1SU

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz here is paste of the main.js code https://pastebin.com/CfamtKxu

Comment: I'm also wondering the same thing. I created a linux package but how to I execute it?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, recent versions of Electron output the packaged app in a "shared library" format on Linux, which the file managers don't recognize as an executable. I found this answer sufficiently explained why this issue occurs and different ways to work around it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064060/4774167

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found the answer here:

https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-installer-debian-package/

Comment: how did you manage to run the project like .exe for windows so what is for Linux?