# ElectronJS app no executing on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: electron

I have build an electron app that works fine with `electron .`. When I build that app using `electron-packager` it is working fine on Mac. However, I need that app to run on Linux. & I have ubuntu for OS.

when I run  `electron-packager . --out=\"build\" --overwrite --icon=\"icons/icon.png\"` it builds the files and executable. But it won't open or execute. Double click would give me a popup window says `Couldn't display the app. No application installed for shared library`.

Few things to notice that -

1. It does not show the icon it suppose to show.
2. I have checked the permission of that file by right click - it `Allow executing file as program` is checked.

I have done all the googling I can. no luck. I have tried `electron-builder` npm as well. NO luck. I really need little help here plz. Really stuck, feels like I have nowhere to go. Help please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron executable not recognized by Nautilus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060402/electron-executable-not-recognized-by-nautilus)

Comment: tried that. didn't work

Comment: Be more specific. What didn't work, how did it not work. There are two things to do in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
electron-packager . appname --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=icons/icon.png --prune=true --out=build
```