# Can't use an Electron built app on Rasbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, electron, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm working on an Electron project, and I wanted to run it on my raspberry pi 3 B+, which is on Raspbian (installed with NOOBS). I first tried to build my electron app with the following command, and then import it on my rasp through ssh.

`npm run electron:linux`

The app runs on my computer just fine, but it doesn't launch on my raspberry. I then tried to just git clone my whole project directly on it, but again, I didn't succeed to make it work.
Does anyone know why it doesn't work on Raspbian ?

Comment: Perhaps this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249925/how-to-run-packaged-electron-app-on-linux

Comment: I checked your link but unfortunatly it didn't help much, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue by myself.

On my computer, I was building my app with the following command:

`npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --linux` (aka `npm run electron:linux`)

But this won't work on raspbian as it works differently. To build correctly my electron app for a raspberry pi, I needed to use this following command instead, with the option **--armv7**:

`npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --linux --armv7`

I hope this answer will help some of you in the future !

Comment: Hey, 
didn't work for me the armv7 but thanks a lot because:
for me works `npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --linux --armv7l`

Comment: electron-build build -l --armv7l